# Android can I send push notification to a device using his gmail only?

Tags: android, notifications, gmail

I know this is weird by i have a question Can i send a notification to an android device without having his token? i mean that the device does not install the app but i need to send him push notification using his gmail only(gmail is a identifier of device).

Comment: ok         .................

Comment: you could send him an email instead...... especially if the device has not installed your app.